# pip package install but i got SyntaxError: invalid syntax in (venv)

Tags: python, tweepy

i used pip to install tweepy package, if i run pip list commend i see tweepy             3.3.0 there installed but when i run my code i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ramib/Desktop/project/PracticeProject/MiningTwitterData.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "/home/ramib/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener
  File "/home/ramib/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 340
    def _start(self, async):
                     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That is an old version from 2015, async has been a keyword since 3.5, so the code breaks. Install a newer version of tweepy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tweepy 3.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/tweepy/3.3.0/) is over 8 years old and does not work on Python 3.10. `async` is being used as a parameter name here, but it [became a keyword](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/) in Python 3.7 (having been deprecated as a variable name since Python 3.5), making such usage invalid.

You probably want to install the latest version of tweepy instead. `pip install tweepy` should do this.

Comment: FWIW, `async` technically only became ["softly deprecated"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans) in Python 3.5, and wasn't made an actual keyword [until Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)